# How to get images from Mobile Game Application?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, google-play-games

I am making some Landing Pages and I need original images from mobile games applications. 
I have iOS but no problem if you have solution with Android.

I just want to get like images, sounds from some game like “Clash Royae”, “Clash of Clans” something like that.

I can’t find anything usefull on Google...

Looking for fast responde, 
Have a nice day!

Comment: Do you have the rights to those images. You can not just grab the images and sound from any game since they are copyrighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request you are making is probably takes long to get the images and sounds. You need to install emulator and get the file from application like .apk and have an application to uncompressed it. Then you will see all the files used in the application.